# Brightway2, Wurst - KeyError: "Can't find this location" in geomatcher.intersects(('IMAGE', reg)) function replicating Mendoza Beltran et al., 2018

Tags: python, brightway

I'm currently learning BW2 and Wurst packages, and I'm new to Python. I've been attempting to replicate *"When the background matters: Using scenarios from integrated assessment models in prospective lifecycle assessment"* by Mendoza Beltran et al. (2018) using EcoInvent 3.6. If anyone's also replicated the study any help with the problem below would be awesome!:)

In creating regional versions of the additional datasets, *add_new_locations_to_added_datasets(input_db)* is being called that calls on *geomatcher.intersects(('IMAGE', reg))* to create a new version of all added electricity generation datasets for each IMAGE region in the Integrated Assessment Model. However, I seem to keep getting *KeyError: "Can't find this location"* and I think there is an obvious adjustment/fix in the regions/locations I need to make from the provided code but my beginner brain can't seem to work backwards and solve this. I can provide more information in case anything's unclear or needs further defining.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [89], in <module>
----> 1 add_new_locations_to_added_datasets(input_db)

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_19308\2544958206.py:13, in add_new_locations_to_added_datasets(db)
     11 possibles = {}
     12 for reg in REGIONS[:-1]:
---> 13     temp= [x for x in geomatcher.intersects(('IMAGE', reg))if type(x) !=tuple]
     14     possibles[reg] = [x for x in temp if len(ecoinvent_to_image_locations(x)) ==1 ]
     15     if not len(possibles[reg]): print(reg, ' has no good candidate')

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\constructive_geometries\geomatcher.py:152, in Geomatcher.intersects(self, key, include_self, exclusive, biggest_first, only)
    149 if key == "RoW" and "RoW" not in self:
    150     return ["RoW"] if "RoW" in possibles else []
--> 152 faces = self[key]
    153 lst = [
    154     (k, (len(v.intersection(faces)), len(v)))
    155     for k, v in possibles.items()
    156     if (faces.intersection(v))
    157 ]
    158 return self._finish_filter(lst, key, include_self, exclusive, biggest_first)

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\constructive_geometries\geomatcher.py:72, in Geomatcher.__getitem__(self, key)
     70 if key == "RoW" and "RoW" not in self.topology:
     71     return set()
---> 72 return self.topology[self._actual_key(key)]

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\bw2\lib\site-packages\constructive_geometries\geomatcher.py:105, in Geomatcher._actual_key(self, key)
    102             print("Geomatcher: Used '{}' for '{}'".format(new, key))
    103         return new
--> 105 raise KeyError("Can't find this location")

KeyError: "Can't find this location"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IMAGE region labels were [changed in 2021](https://github.com/polca/wurst/commit/db8cc9d89ee98fcc14657736632df191e8cbf34a). Not sure why, but I guess this is what is causing the error. Probably `wurst` was adapted to use newer `IMAGE` scenarios, or something similar.

You can use `%debug` to start a debugger print the exact location which is causing the error, and add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. IMAGE region labels in Wurst have been updated, hence, in the provided *Image variable names-correct.csv* spreadsheet the names needed to be updated, as suggested by Chris Mutel in comments.
2. In the _*Functions_to_modify_ecoinvent* notebook being used, for function *add_new_locations_to_added_datasets(db)* below, the *[x for x in temp if len(ecoinvent_to_image_locations(x)) ==*1*]* list comprehension needed to be changed to *==2*  to match EcoInvent's two letter code to provide possibles. Not sure if this was due to an update or an accidental typo.

```
def add_new_locations_to_added_datasets(db):
    # We create a new version of all added electricity generation datasets for each IMAGE region. 
    # We allow the upstream production to remain global, as we are mostly interested in regionalizing 
    # to take advantage of the regionalized IMAGE data.
    
    # step 1: make copies of all datasets for new locations
    # best would be to regionalize datasets for every location with an electricity market like this:
    # locations = {x['location'] for x in get_many(db, *electricity_market_filter_high_voltage)}  
    
    # but this takes quite a long time. For now, we just use 1 location that is uniquely in each IMAGE region.
    possibles = {}
    for reg in REGIONS[:-1]:
        temp= [x for x in geomatcher.intersects(('IMAGE', reg))if type(x) !=tuple]
        possibles[reg] = [x for x in temp if len(ecoinvent_to_image_locations(x)) ==2 ]
        if not len(possibles[reg]): print(reg, ' has no good candidate')
    locations = [v[0] for v in possibles.values()]
```

3. For anyone using newer versions of EcoInvent, where previously the *IAI Area* regions needed to be fixed in the *rename_locations(input_db, fix_names)* that's longer needed as they've been updated. Additionally, for writing results back into database the *rename_locations(db, **fix_names_back**)* function needs to be *rename_locations(db, **fix_names**)*

```
# These locations aren't found correctly by the constructive geometries library - we correct them here:
fix_names= {'CSG' : 'CN-CSG',
            'SGCC': 'CN-SGCC',
             
             'RFC' : 'US-RFC',
             'SERC' : 'US-SERC',
             'TRE': 'US-TRE',
             'ASCC': 'US-ASCC',
             'HICC': 'US-HICC',
             'FRCC': 'US-FRCC',
             'SPP' : 'US-SPP',
            'MRO, US only' : 'US-MRO', 
             'NPCC, US only': 'US-NPCC', 
             'WECC, US only': 'US-WECC',
             
             'IAI Area 1, Africa':'IAI Area, Africa',
             'IAI Area 3, South America':'IAI Area, South America',
             'IAI Area 4&5, without China':'IAI Area, Asia, without China and GCC',
             'IAI Area 2, without Quebec':'IAI Area, North America, without Quebec',
             'IAI Area 8, Gulf':'IAI Area, Gulf Cooperation Council',
            }


fix_names_back = {v:k for k,v in fix_names.items()}


def rename_locations(db, name_dict):
    for ds in db:
        if ds['location'] in name_dict:
            ds['location'] = name_dict[ds['location']]

        for exc in w.technosphere(ds):
            if exc['location'] in name_dict:
                exc['location'] = name_dict[exc['location']]
    
rename_locations(input_db, fix_names)
```

```
for key in database_dict.keys():
    db = database_dict[key]['db']
    rename_locations(db, fix_names_back)
    write_brightway2_database(db, key)
```